# RoR: Collection_select undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collection-select

I previously ask this question but messed up the OP. The official docs for this are not the best and a little confusing. I am trying to gather options from a feedback table and render them in a dropdown on a form and then save them in a table called "answers" and column called "feedback_request" using collection_select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :feedback_request, Feedback.order(:feedback_option), :id, :feedback_request, {prompt: "Feedback"}, {class: "select large-1 behaviourForm"} %>
```

Answers table:

```
  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.integer  "user_id",             limit: 4
        t.string   "subject",             limit: 4
        t.string   "source",              limit: 45
        t.text     "description",         limit: 65535
        t.string   "significance",        limit: 45
        t.string   "feedback_request"
        t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
    end

  add_index "answers", ["feedback_request"], name: "feedback_index"
  add_index "answers", ["significance"], name: "signif_index"
  add_index "answers", ["source"], name: "source_index"
  add_index "answers", ["subject"], name: "FK_HOM_MOD_idx"
  add_index "answers", ["user_id"], name: "teacher_answer_index"
```

Feedback table

```
create_table "feedback", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "feedback_option", limit: 45
  end
```

Models

```
feedback.rb

    class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'feedback'
        has_many :answers, :class_name => 'Answer'
    end

answer.rb

    belongs_to :feedback, :class_name => 'Feedback', :foreign_key => :feedback_request
```

Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @answer do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :feedback_request, Feedback.order(:feedback_option), :id, :feedback_request, {prompt: "Feedback"}, {class: "select large-1 behaviourForm"} %><br>

    <%= f.text_field :Due, :id => "datepicker", placeholder: "Due", data: { no_turbolink: true }, class: "behaviourForm select large-1" %>

   <%= f.input :source, :as => :text, input_html: { :style=> 'width: 100%;', :rows => 2} %>

  <%= f.input :description, :label => "Comments", :as => :text, input_html: { :style=> 'width: 100%;', :rows => 2} %>


  <%= f.button :submit,'Create', class: "small button buttonSelect" %>   
<% end %>
```

This gives me the following error on form load:

```
**undefined method `feedback_request' for #<Feedback id: 1, feedback_option: "Curriculum Management">**
```

Like I say I checked the docs and it's not clear. Any guidance much appreciated as i'm tearing my hair out. Thanks.

Comment: The error message tells you that you try to call `feedback_request` on a `Feedback` not on an `Answer`. Can you please add the full form (not just the line)?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I added my form...

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.collection_select :feedback_request, Feedback.order(:feedback_option), :id, :feedback_request, {prompt: "Feedback"}, {class: "select large-1 behaviourForm"} %><br>
```

The fourth argument `:feedback_request` is a method that is called on each of your feedbacks to determine the option name. You probably want this to be `:feedback_option` instead.

Edit: The third argument is the instance method on `Feedback` whose value will be assigned to `Answer#feedback_request`. So if you want that to be the `:feedback_option` string change it.

```
<%= f.collection_select :feedback_request, Feedback.order(:feedback_option), :feedback_option, :feedback_option, {prompt: "Feedback"}, {class: "select large-1 behaviourForm"} %><br>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks very much, that works sort of but it's printing the id rather than the string?? It's printing "1" in my table...

Comment: Edited my answer with the solution to that.

Comment: Thanks. Should I be getting an id here instead of a string - ie should it be feedback_id instead of feedback_request? I tried to filter in active admin on feedback based on your answer and nothing comes up, but when I say :feedback_id as first argument instead then it filters. But I still want to fill the feedback_request column...that's a bit of a pickle.

Comment: Yeah, `:feedback_id`  and `:id` is how I would do it. Do you really need to fill in `feedback_request`? You can just get that information from the feedback. If you do you can add code that handles that in the model.

Comment: I think it's best to go with feedback_id as I just want to be sure on the integrity of the data. <%= f.collection_select :feedback_id, Feedback.order(:feedback_option), :id, :feedback_option, {prompt: "Feedback"}, {class: "select large-1 behaviourForm"} %> So i'm doing this. Problem is nothing is showing up, although the good thing is the filter I mentioned works. Thanks for your help, any tip on defining the labeling in the model? Cheers.